# Initialize Spring Boot on websphere 8.5.5.9

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, maven-3

i'm trying to run a Spring boot application on Webpshere 8.5.5.9

The code works fine if runned as java main on a embedded tomcat, but if i try to deploy on webpshere, the EAR starts with no error but no rest services are deployed. I don't see in server console the SPRING BOOT LOG. It's not started.

If i make a get on server context path i reveive an hello world! (ear deployed successfully) but at the address of rest service i get a 404 (File not found)

I used spring boot as BOM insted of parent because i already have a parent.
My software stack is:

- Java 8
- JEE 6
- Spring boot 1.5.9 RELEASE
- Maven 3.5.X
- Websphere 8.5.5.9

Any suggestion? Thanks

START CLASS

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class ApplicationConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.out.println("*** CONFIGURING ***");
        return application.sources(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ApplicationContext ctx = 
        System.out.println("*** STARTING MAIN ***");
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class, args);
        //System.out.println(ctx);
    }

    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/sayhello")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World! Test";
    }
}
```

A WAR is packed in a EAR
Important part of POM.xml of WAR is:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>    
  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'd suggest starting on 17.0.0.4 which is the most recent version of Liberty. 8.5.5.9 is almost 2 years old. I'd also suggest pasting any logs and server configuration.

Comment: It might not be Liberty, Liberty is not mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: I cannot change the WAS version, because it is a client requirement. I don't have any custom configuration. I'm using the default one installed with WAS. Do you have any suggests ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe i should add something in web.xml? I've found an example with servlet 2.5. I've 3.0

Comment: @Mishima, how finally did you cause Spring to start ? i have the same issue, i don't see Spring start logging. i suppose to call `main` method manually from some place after server loaded ?!

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure Webspehere is pointing to sdk 1.7_64  or 32
   Please check documention on how to change profile to use sdkname
   {PROFILE}\bin>managesdk.bat -listEnabledProfile -profileName {PROFILE} -verbose
   see it is displaying 1.7_64   or 1.7_32

{PROFILE}\bin>managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName {PROFILE} -sdkname 1.7_64 -enableServers

2. Change JVM Argument to -Dclassinfocachesize=10000

This worked for me.
Please try

Sujith Kasthoori